# Why does Naive Bayes use gaussian pf rather than Student's t?

Tags: normal-distribution, naive-bayes, t-distribution

Every source in the literature I could find about naive Bayes mentions using a gaussian's probability density function, using the mean and variance estimated from the data itself.

This strikes me as odd. If one **estimates** the variance and mean of the data (as opposed to has a prior assumption about it), than the distribution should be student t, not gaussian.

I recognize that the nuance may be unimportant in some cases, but still. This surprises me as it seems like using gaussian pdf is just a sort of mistake, and using the "correct" distribution has no cost involved. What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you referring to the prior or the posterior, and are you referring to a particular empirical Bayes method? These make a lot of difference (citing a specific example would help). In any case, assuming a normal distribution with a normal-inverse gamma prior gets you to a t-distribution posterior, [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#Continuous_distributions).

Comment: @DavidRobinson He means the distributions of the predictors in a classification problem.  Naive Bayes is really just a density estimation technique and has little to do with Bayesian statistics.

Comment: ^ Really? You have a prior belief about the conditional distributions, that features follow some distribution and you update them after seeing empirical evidence. Can you elaborate on Naive Bayes not being a Bayesian approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the confusion here is that the $t$ distribution is used as the sampling distribution for the *test statistic* $\sqrt{n} (\bar{x} - \mu_0) / s$, and not as a model for the underlying distribution.  In the case of naive Bayes we're talking about the distributions of the features themselves, not the distribution of a statistic.  The fact that the mean and variance are estimated from the data doesn't really enter into our choice of distribution for a given feature.  If anything, the Gaussian should be preferred over the $t$ if for no reason other than the fact that it has a simpler density function.  Still, the Gaussian assumption is almost always very wrong.

Comment: Dsaxton, I almost got it, but not quite.

I would expect the pdf of the distribution for each sample will be in of itself a t distribution density function, since sigma and mu were estimated. Your answer seems to imply that the t distribution is only well defined or valid for hypothesis tests. Could you clarify why you think that is the case?

Comment: Perhaps it would help to ask why you'd expect predictors in a classification problem to have $t$ distributions.  Whether or not you're estimating means and variances from data has nothing to do with whether or not a predictor belongs to some family of distributions.  It either does or doesn't.  However, dividing by $s$ instead of $\sigma$ *does* affect the distribution of the $t$ statistic.

Comment: dsxaton: The point is that if the measurements are distirbuted in a gaussian around a certain $\mu$ and $\sigma$, since you're using the *estimated* gaussian parameters to estimate probability, you're using the  gaussian pdf in a "wrong" way. Specifically, you will greatly underestimate the probability of outliers (since for example  $\sigma$ estimate may be lower than it should be).

In any case, I now realize that student t is only defined for the test statistics and hence useless. Still it seems like there's a self contradiction in the way naive bayes is used.

Comment: If you assume something is normal, it doesn't make sense to decide it's $t$ just because you don't know the parameters.  *That* would be a contradiction.  Also, you can just as easily overestimate $\sigma$ as underestimate it.  In any case, the Gaussian assumption is just a simplifying convention used in naive Bayes and it would partially defeat the purpose to use a complicated density like that of the $t$.

Comment: of course $\sigma$ may be either overestimated or underestimated. The point is that it as it may be underestimated, the likelihood of something being "5 $\sigma$ away is actually much higher than what's implied by a normal distribution.

We're choosing a pdf which will certainly significantly underestimate the chance of extreme outliers *even if all the model's assumptions were completely true*. Thanks to your feedback I'm not sure that I have a reasonable alternative to this, but I still find this self contradiction to be odd.